# ColdFusion autosuggest only matching start of string

Tags: coldfusion, autosuggest, cfc

I am working with the autosuggest attribute of `cfinput`.
But I am not 100% satisfied with how it works.

Here's a little bit of the code :

```
<cfinput id=""town" name="town" type="text" class="form-control" autosuggest="cfc:bind.gettown({cfautosuggestvalue})" showautosuggestloadingicon="false>
```

This control suggests all of the towns with the `cfautosuggestvalue` in it.

Ex: if it contains "lu", it should show all the cities containing this string, like: Luxembourg or Saint Jean-de-Luz
But it is only showing Luxembourg ...

I checked my request `bind.gettown` and it gives me those 2 cities, but I guess that the ColdFusion's autosuggest filters my initial request by removing all the string not starting by 'lu' ... and as you can guess this is a problem.

So my point is to show all the cities containing 'lu' ...

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coldfusion autosuggest not working for suggestions in the middle of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939226/coldfusion-autosuggest-not-working-for-suggestions-in-the-middle-of-the-string)  You just need to add the attribute: `matchContains="true"`.

Comment: Thank you Miguel-F , it's working now !

Comment: "But I am not 100% satisfied with how it works." >> A bit off topic, but this is one of the primary reasons why [ColdFusion UI The Right Way](https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/index.html) was created. If `cfform` tags can be avoided, you'll save yourself some heartache.